# How to fix this error "Function CollectionReference.doc()"

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm creating a small react native app, when i add some code to delete data from firebase it shows me this error: " FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined"

**that's my action:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

const deleteChat = (id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, getFirestore) => {
        if (id !== null) {
            firebase.firestore().collection('chat').doc(id).delete()
                .then(() => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: "DELETE_CHAT",
                        id
                    })
                })
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that you must pass a string to `doc()`.  You're passing something `undefined`.  You should log the value of `id` to be sure what it's receiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only checking if the id is not null. In your case the `id` is undefined.

You can solve this by writing 
`if (id !== null && id !== undefined)`
or even better & shorter (it checks for both null and undefined)

```
if (id) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: it shows me now this "Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: 1557406283650"

Comment: @SoufienJAOUADI apparently you pass the id as number, not as string